# Jquery not working for li a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap nav list.On scrol Ii want to change the color of a tag.
Here is Jquery code

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var os = $('#logo').offset().top;
    var ht = $('#logo').height();
    if (scroll > os + ht) { 
//Not working
$('#header .nav > li > a').css("color", "#333 !important");}  

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="logo-on-scroll" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-10">
                            <a href="">Some text</a>
</div>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mobilemenu">
                            <?php
                            wp_nav_menu(array(

                                'menu_class' => 'nav_menu nav navbar-nav',
                                'theme_location' => 'primary', 'Header menu'));
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Without seeing what the HTML markup looks like, it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: Please read this [mcve]

Comment: None of the elements you are selecting in your javascript example are present in your HTML example.... not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

From [the jQuery docs on `.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc-1):

> Note: `.css()` ignores !important declarations. So, the statement `$( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" )` does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

I would suggest just removing the `!important` entirely, and relying on the high specificity of the inline-style attributes assigned by `.css()`

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var os = $('#logo').offset().top;
  var ht = $('#logo').height();
  if (scroll > os + ht) {
    //Not working
    $('#header .nav > li > a').css("color", "#333");
  }
});
```

Comment: Glad to help! An accept would be appreciated if you have the time :)